# Including all months for the year without duplicates when date ranges can be consecutive or not using T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

I have one or more start and end periods which can be consecutive, overlap, or anything in between.  My goal is to have all 12 months displayed regardless of when the period starts; that is, I can see months before the period, during the period and potentially after the period.  For sake of this example, I'm checking it against 2019 so I want to see all 12 months filled in for 2019.

I have the following sample data to illustrate the problem:

```sql
DECLARE @DATES TABLE (ID int, EffectiveDate date, EffectiveEndDate date)
INSERT INTO @DATES
VALUES
    (43, '2018-10-01', '2019-09-30'),
    (43, '2019-10-01', '2020-09-30'),
    (44, '2019-10-01', '2020-09-30');
```

I also have a "tally" table which has all 12 months and the start of the month (omitted for brevity but it's a temp table with a column called `N` which has a value of 1-12 representing the month, and a column `StartOfMonth` which is the start date of the month.  Now what I want is to have each ID (43 and 44 in this case) show all 12 months.  This is easy with 43 where there are two records that run from October 2018 to November 2020, as it falls within all 12 months.  44 however only gives me October, November and December since there is only one row that begins in October.  I cannot add a row for the previous months.

The Months table is simply defined as the follows:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Months;
CREATE TABLE #Months (N tinyint, StartOfMonth date);
INSERT INTO #Months
VALUES
    (1, DATEFROMPARTS(2019, 1, 1)),
    (2, DATEFROMPARTS(2019, 2, 1)),
    (3, DATEFROMPARTS(2019, 3, 1)),
    (4, DATEFROMPARTS(2019, 4, 1)),
    (5, DATEFROMPARTS(2019, 5, 1)),
    (6, DATEFROMPARTS(2019, 6, 1)),
    (7, DATEFROMPARTS(2019, 7, 1)),
    (8, DATEFROMPARTS(2019, 8, 1)),
    (9, DATEFROMPARTS(2019, 9, 1)),
    (10, DATEFROMPARTS(2019, 10, 1)),
    (11, DATEFROMPARTS(2019, 11, 1)),
    (12, DATEFROMPARTS(2019, 12, 1));
```

Code:

```sql
SELECT Month = m.N, 
       d.ID, 
       d.EffectiveDate, 
       d.EffectiveEndDate,
       -- This flag doesn't mean anything, just so I can better see the results I'm getting
       Ind = CASE
                    WHEN m.StartOfMonth BETWEEN d.EffectiveDate AND d.EffectiveEndDate
                    THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                END
FROM @dates d
     LEFT JOIN #Months m
        ON m.N BETWEEN 1 AND 12
WHERE
    m.StartOfMonth
        BETWEEN EffectiveDate AND EffectiveEndDate
ORDER BY ID, m.N;
```

This gives me the following (wrong) output:

```
Month   ID  EffectiveDate   EffectiveEndDate    Ind
1       43  2018-10-01      2019-09-30          1
2       43  2018-10-01      2019-09-30          1
3       43  2018-10-01      2019-09-30          1
4       43  2018-10-01      2019-09-30          1
5       43  2018-10-01      2019-09-30          1
6       43  2018-10-01      2019-09-30          1
7       43  2018-10-01      2019-09-30          1
8       43  2018-10-01      2019-09-30          1
9       43  2018-10-01      2019-09-30          1
10      43  2019-10-01      2020-09-30          1
11      43  2019-10-01      2020-09-30          1
12      43  2019-10-01      2020-09-30          1
!!! THIS PART IS WRONG !!!
10      44  2019-10-01      2020-09-30          1
11      44  2019-10-01      2020-09-30          1
12      44  2019-10-01      2020-09-30          1
```

If I skip the effective date/effective end date check or try to do some sort of case statement where I say if month begins before the effective date then include it anyway 43 doubles up on the months because there are two rows, while 44 works as expected.

What I need is to get this:

```
Month   ID  EffectiveDate   EffectiveEndDate    Ind
1       43  2018-10-01      2019-09-30          1
2       43  2018-10-01      2019-09-30          1
3       43  2018-10-01      2019-09-30          1
4       43  2018-10-01      2019-09-30          1
5       43  2018-10-01      2019-09-30          1
6       43  2018-10-01      2019-09-30          1
7       43  2018-10-01      2019-09-30          1
8       43  2018-10-01      2019-09-30          1
9       43  2018-10-01      2019-09-30          1
10      43  2019-10-01      2020-09-30          1
11      43  2019-10-01      2020-09-30          1
12      43  2019-10-01      2020-09-30          1
1       44  2019-10-01      2020-09-30          0
2       44  2019-10-01      2020-09-30          0
3       44  2019-10-01      2020-09-30          0
4       44  2019-10-01      2020-09-30          0
5       44  2019-10-01      2020-09-30          0
6       44  2019-10-01      2020-09-30          0
7       44  2019-10-01      2020-09-30          0
8       44  2019-10-01      2020-09-30          0
9       44  2019-10-01      2020-09-30          0
10      44  2019-10-01      2020-09-30          1
11      44  2019-10-01      2020-09-30          1
12      44  2019-10-01      2020-09-30          1
```

where all 12 months are showing for all situations, whether there's consecutive ranges or one range that starts at any given point in the year.

Comment: Can you post the DDL for #months?

Comment: A `left outer join` generates results for every row in the left table, regardless of matches on the right. Since you want every `#Months` row in the output it should either be on the left side of the join or you should change to a `right outer join`.

Comment: A right outer join or moving the #Months table to the left side of the join still gives me the same results (1-12 for the first one, only 10-12 for the second).  I'm pretty sure the issue is the WHERE clause, but haven't been able to figure out how to get it without duplicating months for the first set (the real data has more columns I'm not using in the example so I can't use a DISTINCT)

@AlanBurstein the #Months table is just two columns, N and StartOfmonth, adding values between 1 and 12 for N and then StartOfMonth is just DATEFROMPARTS.  E.g. `VALUES (1, DATEFROMPARTS(2019, 1, 1)`

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a better way to do this, but here is an ugly solution:

```
-- Build base data
DECLARE @DATES TABLE (ID int, EffectiveDate date, EffectiveEndDate date)
INSERT INTO @dates
VALUES
    (43, '2018-10-01', '2019-09-30'),
    (43, '2019-10-01', '2020-09-30'),
    (44, '2019-10-01', '2020-09-30');

DECLARE @months TABLE (StartOfMonth date, n int)

;WITH dateCTE
AS
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY number) - 1  AS rn
  FROM master.dbo.spt_values
)
INSERT @months (StartOfMonth, n)
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(mm, rn, '2018-01-01') AS date) AS StartOfMonth, DATEPART(mm,DATEADD(mm, rn, '2018-01-01')) AS n
FROM dateCTE
WHERE rn < 48

-- build a list of all IDs and months where the ID is active in the year
;with dateCTE
AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT d.ID, m.StartOfMonth, m.n
  FROM @months AS m
  CROSS
  JOIN @dates AS d
  WHERE DATEPART(YEAR,m.StartOfMonth) BETWEEN DATEPART(YEAR,d.EffectiveDate) and DATEPART(YEAR,d.EffectiveEndDate)

)
-- join list from previous step to the activity data
-- this generates the full list with NULLs where the ID was not active
,listCTE
AS
(
  SELECT cd.ID, cd.StartOfMonth, cd.n, d.EffectiveDate, d.EffectiveEndDate
  FROM dateCTE AS cd
  LEFT
  JOIN @dates AS d
  ON   d.ID = cd.ID
  AND  cd.StartOfMonth between d.EffectiveDate AND d.EffectiveEndDate
)
-- fill in the NULLS by joining the table back to itelf
SELECT  n AS [Month],
        ID,
        COALESCE(EffectiveDate, 
                 (SELECT TOP 1 EffectiveDate FROM listCTE AS l2 WHERE l2.ID = l.ID AND l2.EffectiveDate > l.StartOfMonth ORDER BY l2.StartOfMonth DESC),
                 (SELECT TOP 1 EffectiveDate FROM listCTE AS l2 WHERE l2.ID = l.ID AND l2.EffectiveEndDate < l.StartOfMonth ORDER BY l2.StartOfMonth DESC)
        ) AS EffectiveDate,
        COALESCE(EffectiveEndDate, 
                 (SELECT TOP 1 EffectiveEndDate FROM listCTE AS l2 WHERE l2.ID = l.ID AND l2.EffectiveDate > l.StartOfMonth ORDER BY l2.StartOfMonth DESC),
                 (SELECT TOP 1 EffectiveEndDate FROM listCTE AS l2 WHERE l2.ID = l.ID AND l2.EffectiveEndDate < l.StartOfMonth ORDER BY l2.StartOfMonth DESC)
                ) AS EffectiveEndDate,
        CASE
            WHEN StartOfMonth BETWEEN EffectiveDate AND EffectiveEndDate
            THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS Ind,
        StartOfMonth
FROM listCTE AS l
WHERE DATEPART(YEAR,StartOfMonth) = 2019
ORDER BY ID, StartOfMonth
```

(This code uses a `@months` table variable rather than the `#months` temp table in the original)

This works by building a list of all IDs and months, then left-joining that to the `@dates` table to generate the months where each ID is active. Finally, the second result set is joined back to itself to fill in the NULLs.

This is likely to have horrible performance when applied to data at scale; it might be possible to mitigate this by materialising the interim steps of the CTEs into tables (or temp tables) with appropriate indexes.